# Relative locations with compass points

Tags: грамматика, склонение, творительный-падеж

1. I was trying to figure out how to say "x kilometers to the north/west/east/south of y". Which of these alternatives is better?

   - Углич находится на двухстах километрах к северу от Москвы
   - Углич находится двухстами километрами севернее Москвы
   - Углич находится на растоянии двухсот километров к северу от Москвы
2. What if I want to tell just the location in regard to the compass point, without the distance?

   - Углич находится к северу от Москвы
   - Углич находится севернее Москвы
   - Углич находится северной Москвы
3. In a textbook, I saw the following sentence: "Саратов находится **юго-западней** Москвы". If I understood well, "юго-западней" is the instrumental feminine. Why not "юго-западным", since Саратов is masculine?

Comment: although inflexion wise ***юго-западной*** CAN be Instrumental, i perceive it as Genitive, probably because of the Genitive ***Москвы***

Comment: So, is the feminine gender agreeing with Москва?
Does the sentence literally mean "Saratov lies of southwestern Moscow"?

Comment: kind of, if you read it as it's written, but as a whole it's still nonsensical, because verbs cannot take part in constructions of possession which use Genitive, without the verb it would be 'Saratov of south-western Moscow'

Comment: Лев крупнЕЕ (крупнЕЙ) волка. Собака крупнЕЕ (крупнЕЙ) кошки. От Саратова до Самары ближЕ, чем до Москвы. Саратов расположен восточнЕЕ Москвы. ТочнЕЕ сказать — юго-восточнее///It is not the instrumental feminine. It is the comparative.(Все города Среднего и Южного Поволжья находятся юго-восточнее Москвы. Не юго-западнее)

Comment: @Elena the post has been edited, it was ***юго-западнОЙ*** originally

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For "x kilometers to the north of Y" all three options are fine (note that I've corrected them a bit):

```
    Углич находится в двухстах километрах к северу от Москвы
    Углич находится двумястами километрами севернее Москвы
    Углич находится на растоянии двухсот километров к северу от Москвы
```

There is one more option:

```
    Углич находится в двухстах километрах на север от Москвы
```

It's almost same as first one, the difference is in "на север" vs "к северу".

For location in regard to the compass point, without the distance, first two are fine, but the last one in your example is wrong.

```
    Углич находится к северу от Москвы
    Углич находится севернее Москвы
```

As for sentence from textbook: "Саратов находится юго-западной Москвы", I guess there is a mistake. It should be "Саратов находится юго-западней Москвы". And I believe "юго-западней" is an adjective n comparative form here.

Comment: and another option for the point # 1 is ***...находится в двухстах километрах севернее...***

Comment: Я проверил учебник, и, наверное, это я ошибся. Правильно - **юго-западней**; я уже отредактировал свой пост. Всё-таки, грамматическая функция мне чужая. Творительный падеж? Родительный? 
Сравнительный степень? Увы, я только знаю сравнительные окончания *-е* и *-ее*.

Comment: @swrutra *СравнительнАЯ степень?*

Comment: да, сравнительная... всегда путаю род существительных, окончающих по -ь!!!!

Comment: `Углич находится двумястами километрами` - устаревший вариант. Мало кто рискует связываться со склонениями :-)

Answer (score 1):

1) To "X kilometers to the north/west/east/south of Y"..

1a) ..the (arguably) most used equivalent would be "в X [in prepositive] километрах к северу/западу/востоку/югу от Y [in genitive]", or the one completely equivalent to it, "на север/запад/восток/юг от Y [genitive]",

1b) the variant with "...на расстоянии..." [X in genitive] would be more suitable to point out the correct distance,

1c) and the variant with "...двумястами..." [X in instrumentative] would be somewhat more expressive.

2) The location in regard to the compass point (in your example) should be expressed as any one of:

2a) "...севернее..." or "...северней..." [Y in genitive in both cases], the 2nd form is just the 1st form with its ending contracted ("-ее" -> "-ей");

2b) "...к северу от..." or "...на север от..." [Y in genitive in both cases].

2c) There's also the "... по направлению на север от... [Y in genitive]" -- "in the north direction off [Y...]".

Comment: Ok. I'll take "Углич находится в двухстах километрах к северу от Москвы" and "Углич находится к северу от Москвы" for future usage.

As for юго-западней, my doubt appears to be solved. Is it an alternative to юго-западнее I wasn't aware of previously?

Comment: Both "-ее" and "-ей" are completely interchangeable in spoken language (so you might encounter both in one phrase spoken by one person), and some might say the "-ее" (full form) is more suitable for the official style, both spoken and written. For a *rough* comparison think "will not" vs. "won't".

Answer (score 1):

- *Углич находится на двухстах километрах к северу от Москвы* -
  "Углич находится **в** двухстах километрах к северу от Москвы" This would probably be the most common colloquial use case. There may be an alternative: "Углич находится на двух**сотом** километр**е** к северу от Москвы", which implies that the distance is metered on railroad or highway.
- *Углич находится двухстами километрами севернее Москвы* - Usable, but less practical.
- *Углич находится на растоянии двухсот километров к северу от Москвы* - Definitely usable, but not colloquial. It sounds like a geography lesson.
- *Углич находится к северу от Москвы* - perfectly fine. A variant "Углич находится **на** север от Москвы" implies a stricter sense of direction.
- *Углич находится севернее Москвы* - defines latitude, but not direction. Same as "Stockholm is farther to the north than Moscow".
- *Углич находится северной Москвы* - not good at all. "северной Москвы" means it is about the northern part of Moscow, and the sentence 
  as a whole makes no grammatical sense.

№3 (*юго-западней*) I think it is sufficiently resolved already, as the question reflects it.